# How to find index of max array element recursively

Tags: c++, c, arrays, recursion

I want to find the index of biggest element of an array recursively. The declaration of the function can be like this:

```
int maxIndex(const int *p, int size)
```

I was studying recursion and I saw some examples, like finding the max array element recursively. That is simple like this:

```
int maxInt( const int * p, int size)   
{

    if(size == 1)
        return *p;

    int max = maxInt(p + 1, size -1 );

    if(max > *p)
        return max;
    else
        return p[0];
}
```

And I asked myself that how can I find the index which includes max element of the array.
I am not even sure it is possible. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is possible for anybody who really understands how the code above works.

Comment: This is not a problem that I would try to solve with a recursive algorithm.  I understand you're trying to learn but this is not the kind of problem I would pick to learn on.  You have to look at every element to determine the largest (unless they are ordered) so why not just loop over them?   A recursive algorithm is going to use more memory and IMO is harder to get your head around.  Important if you or someone else ever needs to modify the code.  Just my opinion.

Comment: I could not solve that I don't know why maybe you are right I didn't understand recursion very well..

Comment: If you don't understand the code in the question, why are you wanting to move on from it?

Comment: Instead of returning the current maximum, return its location/index.

Comment: @JJF it's possible enes K has no choice in the matter, an instructor may have handed this out as an assignment regardless of how inappropriate you or I might think recursion is for this problem.

Comment: @pjs it would have to be the location, since the index is not known within the recursion.

Comment: @WeatherVane the index is easy enough to derive.

Comment: @pjs the base of the array is not passed so the index would need to be adjusted after every recursive call.

Comment: @WeatherVane Or you could return the size parameter, if we want to make it unreadable :P.

Comment: @MillieSmith the well-received answer from "dasblinkenlight" is returning the pointer not the index, which only needs calculating once.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know that's the right way to do it, I'm just messing around.

Comment: @MillieSmith So returning index is possible or not? I don't want to return the address... I could do it

Comment: @enesK You *do* want to return the address (edit: just noticed that returns int*, which is against your hw...). It's cleaner code. You *could* return size and then use that up the recursion chain to calculate the actual index, but it's more confusing and is the same idea. If you change the size parameter to `int maxInt( const int* p, int size, int index)` and call `maxInt(p, size, index + 1)`, you could write it in a way in which you return the index and not the location. If you're allowed two functions, you can wrap it in `int maxInt( const int* p, int size ) { return maxInt(p, size, 0); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want with the function header you want. The index returned from `maxInt` needs to be adjusted at each level of recursion, which I do with the `+ 1` part.

```
int maxInt(const int* p, int size)
{
    if (size == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int max = maxInt(p + 1, size - 1) + 1;
    return p[max] > *p ? max : 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that every time the code in the question returns, it is returning the value pointed to, and not its index in the array (`*p` and `p[0]`).

Comment: @enesK You're welcome. You also returned the wrong stuff, as I point out at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely possible: all you need to do is to modify code to return a pointer to max int, and then subtracting the initial pointer from the return value of `maxInt` in C, or using [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) in C++.

```
const int* maxInt( const int * p, int size)  {
    if(size == 1)
        return p;
    int *maxPtr = maxInt(p + 1, size -1 );
    if(*maxPtr > *p)
        return maxPtr;
    else
        return p;
}
```

In C:

```
int index = maxInt(array, size) - array;
```

In C++:

```
ptrdiff_t index = std::distance(maxInt(array, size), array);
```

**Note:** Solving this problem using recursion should only be considered as part of a learning exercise, because of a very real possibility of overflowing the stack. The same applies to any other problem with potentially high number of recursive invocations and no tail call optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Let's make a bonus question out of it. What's the main problem with recursion here? The main problem is that you end up having as many times maxInt called as you have elements. This is going to happen at the same time, i.e., call stack will look following:

```
maxInt
 maxInt
  maxInt
   ...
```

Given that the call stack is limited to several hundreds call on modern systems (even less, may be) this solution isn't practical. However, can we make it more practical? Yes, we can - if we transform the current recursion into something which is called `tail recursion` - that is, when recursion call is happening at the very end of the function - we can employ so-called 'tail-call optimization', which makes sure the recursion does not actually call a function, but behaves like a loop, and end up with the flexibility and performance of the loop. Like I said, the key is to make sure the function is called in the end. Here is how we can do this:

```
int maxInt( const int * p, int size, int curr_max)   
{
    curr_max = (curr_max > *p) ? curr_max : *p;
    if(size == 1)
        return curr_max;

    return maxInt(p + 1, size -1, curr_max);
}
```

If you look into assembly language generated for this function is any optimization above O1, you will see that there is no recursion function call there, but instead there is a loop.

This solution can than be combined with one from dasblinkenlight to provide a solution to OP's homework.

Answer (score -1):

```
to find the first index of a number....if same element are occurring multiple times example [9,8,10,8] and we have to find the first index of element 8. 
int firstIndex(int input[], int size, int x) {

  if(size==0)
  {
    return -1;
  }

  if(input[0]==x)
  {
    return 0 ;
  }

  int ans = firstIndex(input+1,size-1,x);
  if(ans==-1)
  {
    return -1;
  }else if(ans!=-1)
  { 
    return ans+1;
    }
}
```